# Permutations with both repeating and non-repeating elements, partially figured out formula

Tags: combinations, permutation

I'm trying to find the formula to calculate the amount of permutations for x # of elements that can repeat, y # of elements that cannot repeat, and z # of spaces/slots. So far I figured out the parts for when only x elements are included: x^z, and when all elements are included but none act as repeating: ((x+y)!)/(((x+y)-z)!), which are basic derivations of known combinations and permutations formulas. These added together + the cases where repeatable and non-repeatable elements are both present, and repeatable elements are repeating at least once would be the total number of permutations, but I can't seem to narrow down the formula for that part. Any guidance would be apprecaited.

Comment: Ey! This is not a topic of stack overflow, but maybe of https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that was a thing but I shall switch there now.